# Ubuntu Server MOTD

Tags: server, ssh, motd

I have a Ubuntu server 16.04 installation and I'm trying to get rid of the message of the day.

I've already disabled all the files in `/etc/update-motd.d/` and 
`run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`
Doesnt't output anything.

In addition to that I've commented out the motd lines in those 2 files:

```
/etc/pam.d/login
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

The problem is that I'm still getting system information printed whenever I login over ssh.

Does anyone know where this could be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around in the `sshd_config` file, I found the `Banner` option and that referenced the file `/etc/issue`. Said file contained exactly the message I was seeing on each ssh login. I've commented out the Banner option and that fixed the issue. Hope that helps someone in the future.