# Message of the Day stopped working

Tags: motd

I'm running 22.04.1 LTS server.  After a reboot today, the message of the day stopped working (the system statistics you see when you ssh into the machine).  Now, all I see is the record of the last login.  I haven't edited any configuration files, and all sources indicate that the service is still enabled.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue on latest sources?

Comment: MOTD only shows once a day (*NOT* on every login), can you confirm you haven't logged in via SSH yet today? Can you wait a day and see if the  MOTD shows up again?

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the right terminology.  I'm used to seeing this on every login:

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sun Oct 23 05:58:35 AM UTC 2022

  System load:  2.5693359375       Temperature:              40.0 C
  Usage of /:   3.4% of 230.67GB   Processes:                133
  Memory usage: 6%                 Users logged in:          1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1

...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837416/ubuntu-server-motd?rq=1